# .net 3,5 feature failed to "install" on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installshield

i have suite created in InstallShield which contains multiple packages. One of them requires .net 3.5 so in the package view i added Windows Feature NetFx3. Everything worked perfectly but today i got hands on a machine where instalation is terminated with the following errors in the log:

```
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: Getting feature list for initial feature items 'NetFx3'
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: Getting feature items for OS version 1000 (Client)
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: Final feature list for current item is: NetFx3
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: Installing Windows features for parcel 'PackageXY'...
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: Engine: property 'ISInstallStatus' value now 'Windows-Funktionen/-Rollen werden installiert …'
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: Engine: property 'ISParcelStatus' value now ''
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: CWindowsFeatureParcel::Install: using DismAPI on Windows 8 or newer
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: Engine: request for proxy handler, 0, 1
5-17-2017[02:03:10]: No source paths specified for DismEnableFeature
5-17-2017[02:05:19]: UI DLL: Resource 'Header_bckgnd.png' -> 'C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Local\Temp\{270DDFC5-A522-4510-8282-DE76EBB713E6}\Header_bckgnd.png'
5-17-2017[02:05:20]: UI DLL: Resource 'Header_bckgnd.png' -> 'C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Local\Temp\{270DDFC5-A522-4510-8282-DE76EBB713E6}\Header_bckgnd.png'
5-17-2017[02:05:26]: CWindowsFeatureParcel::CallDismApi result: 0x00000001
5-17-2017[02:05:26]: Windows feature install result status: 0x80070001
5-17-2017[02:05:26]: Failed installing Windows features for parcel 'PackageXY', error 0x80070001
5-17-2017[02:05:26]: Engine: property 'ISInstallStatus' value now 'IDS_SUITE_INTERRUPTED'
```

I have tried following:

- run DISM  /Online  /Enable-Feature  /FeatureName:NetFx3  /All  /LimitAccess  /Source:x:\sources\sxs and other variations of this command that i wasnt really sure what are supposed to do
- disabled the feature manualy and re-enabled, multiple times in different order together with the .net 4.7 and run the setup with different configuration of the checked features.

Without luck so far, the thing that bothers me the most is its only happening on this particular Virtual Machine, which is up to date with the Windows Update.

**edit: It is happening on every machine that has Creators Update installed, which comes with the .net 4.7**

**edit2: i did not solve this issue, i just removed the funcionality that is allowing the windows feature for the packages.**

Answer (score 0):

Our application requires .NET 3.5 and internal testing indicates that .net framework 3.5 still gets installed using the suite prerequisite feature install.

I have seen times in the past where I had similar issues but that was an issue with VMWare Workstation and using NAT instead of Bridged network settings. In all of these cases, as you indicated, running DISM from powershell or a cmd prompt would also fail. Switching to Bridged allowed this to work. I cannot explain why.

Unfortunately we are dependent on .Net 3.5 due to 3rd party software dependencies, one of which is SQL Server 2012 believe it or not!

Comment: thank you for you input, however that doesnt really help me much. Since previously released versions had this "feature" and now all thej installations are blocked on the W10 with Creators update. I have workaround for our product, but its kind of a painful process.. so i was wondering if theres anything that could be done on the target machine, to unblock the installation.